# Is saying 「XはYは…」 acceptable?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-は, child-speech

In いっすんぼうし, a very popular fairy tale, this line appears:

> **だいじんは　からだは**　ちいさいけれど　げんきな
>   いっすんぼうしを　たいそう　きにいり
>   じぶんの　いえで　はたらかせることにしました。

Is 「だいじんは　からだは」 grammatically correct? What would be done to make this more correct?

Comment: It couldn't be more correct.

Comment: I thought it was, but I've never seen it before, so I'm a bit curious about it.

Comment: Why did you believe it was incorrect? What rule did you think the construction violated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sequence 体は小さいけれど元気な serves as an adjectival block which modifies [一寸法師]{いっすんぼうし}. 
体は小さいけれど元気な一寸法師 is object of the verb 気に入り, in turn. [大臣]{だいじん}(は) is its subject.
So, the whole sentence has kind of a nested structure, and the two は belong to different levels respectively.