# Is it possible to use more than one を in a sentence?

Tags: particle-を

I wasn't sure since as far as I know, we cannot repeat は or が　(or am I wrong about this?). I'm quite certain though that we can repeat の and に. But how about を as in this sentence below?

私は封筒にきって**を**はるの**を**忘れた?

Comment: は or が can repeat themselves too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, を can be repeated in a sentence.
And your sentence is perfectly correct:
私は封筒に切手を貼るのを忘れた。
I forgot to put a stamp on the envelope.

In this case the sentence is unambiguous because the corresponding verb immediately follows を.

Comment: In this case, if I change it a bit into this, will it still be correct or wrong? 私は封筒にきってをはる(のは)忘れた

Comment: If you include のは, yes. You are just replacing を for は.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple を may appear in one sentence when it's a [complex sentence](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/complex-sentence-examples.html) or compound sentence (i.e. has more then one clause).

> 私は封筒にきってをはるのを忘れた。

This is a typical complex sentence. 封筒に切手【きって】を貼【は】るの forms a *noun clause* meaning "to put a stamp on the envelope". It serves as the object of the outer main clause, 私は～を忘れた ("I forgot ～").

Similar question: [Is saying 「XはYは…」 acceptable?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19461/5010)