# 日本語における relative clause (関係詞節?) とは？

Tags: relative-clauses

[relative-clauses] のタグをなんとなく眺めてみました。これは、直訳すれば「関係詞節」らしいですが、日本語にこのような文法は存在しますか？というのも、いまいち日本語の文法でこのような文節を意識したことがなく、はたして日本語の文法において関係詞節なるものが存在するのかふと疑問に思ったからです。そして、試しに Google で検索すると英文法についてのサイトがひたすらヒットします。

存在する場合は、例えばどのような文章のどのような用法になりますか？

Comment: https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=NDknf0v40gkC&pg=PA10#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: タグの説明を見るとわかると思いますが（追記したの僕ですが）、完全に等価ではないですが日本語のそのようなものは「連体（修飾）節」と呼ばれるのが一般的です。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

日本語にも関係節にあたるものは存在します。日本人が関係節を意識しないのは、単純にネイティブスピーカーは母語の文法なんて意識せずに使っているからです（特別なトレーニングを受けていない英語のネイティブスピーカーは a と the の区別をうまく説明できません）。Googleで検索しても日本語文法の情報が上位にヒットしないのは、単純に日本人がその単語を検索するときはたいてい英文法の情報を求めているからです。

英語話者向けの日本語の関係節の説明記事には、例えば以下のようなものがあります。

- [Relative clauses distinguishing whom/with which/that](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14541/5010)
- [Wasabi: Japanese Relative Clauses](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/japanese-relative-clauses/)

日本語の関係節には、以下のようなパターンがあります。

> 1. **噂を聞いた人** the person who heard the rumor
>      （「人」は「聞いた」の主語）
> 2. **私が聞いた噂** the rumor which I heard
>      （「噂」は「聞いた」の目的語）
> 3. **私が衝撃を受けた噂**　the rumor by which I was shocked
>      （「噂(に)」は「受けた」の主語でも目的語でもなく、副詞的修飾語）
> 4. **彼が結婚した噂** the rumor that he married
>      （「噂」は「彼が結婚した」の主語でも目的語でもなく、関係節は噂の内容説明）

日本語の関係節を英語の関係節と比較しつつ特徴を述べると、以下のような感じになります。

- 英語と日本語では語順が大きく異なります。日本語では被修飾語は関係節（修飾節）の「後」に来ます。これはまあ当たり前ですね。日本語は大事な成分を最後に持っていく言語です（[主要部終端型言語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%BB%E8%A6%81%E9%83%A8)）。
- 英語には「関係代名詞/関係副詞」 (which, that, whom, when, where, why, whose, ...) というものが存在し、これにより被修飾語（先行詞）と関係節との文法的関係性を明示するのですが、日本語にはこれにあたる語は存在しません。基本的には、「関係節を作る前の元の文」から要素を後ろに動かして助詞を**省く**だけで、たいていの日本語の関係節は作ることができます。乱暴に言えば被修飾語と関係節とはそれこそ意味的に関係さえしていればいいので、「聞いた時間」と「聞いた理由」と「聞いた場所」と「聞いた内容」と「聞いた人」は、日本語だと同じに見えます。このシンプルさが、逆に日本人が日本語の関係節を意識しづらい理由なのかもしれません。
- 基本的には、関係節の中で、助詞の「は」は使われず、代わりに「が」が使われます。

  > 私**は**本を読んだ。 → 私**が**読んだ本（は面白かった。）

  これは、「は」は文全体の話題を取り立てて示すのに使われる助詞であり、関係節は本質的に文全体の話題ではないからです。ただし「は」には「対照性 (contrast) を示す」という別の大きな役割があるので、[こういう文](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19461/5010)は存在することがあります。
- さらに、関係節中では、多くの場合に主語を示す「が」を、[「の」に置き換えることができます](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/5010)。意味はほぼ全く変わりません。

  > 私**が**読んだ本 ＝ 私**の**読んだ本

日本語では関係代名詞/副詞で文法的役割を明示しないため、ときどき意味が曖昧になることがあり、日本語学習者が悩むことになります。relative-clauseのタグを追っているならもう気づいているかもしれませんが、「太郎が好きな花子」というフレーズは、文脈によって「太郎のことが好きな花子 (Hanako who likes Taro)」と「太郎が好いている花子 (Hanako whom Taro likes)」の両方の意味をとりえます。「紹介した人」というフレーズを見た場合も、この「人」が主語なのか目的語なのか副詞的なのか曖昧なので、英語に翻訳する時には "the person who introduced someone" なのか "the person whom someone introduced" なのか "the person to whom someone introduced" なのか、文脈によって決定する必要があります。

こういう文法構造は、「英語話者が第2言語として日本語を学ぶ」というサイトでは、ほぼ一貫して relative clause と呼ばれていると思います。ただし、いわゆる「国文法」においてこういう文法構造がどう呼ばれているのかは、よく知りません。本居宣長は別の説明をしていたかもしれませんし、「連体修飾節」とか、別の名前がついているかもしれません。（日本人が中学校で学ぶ文法と、外国人が日本語を学ぶときの文法用語にはかなりの乖離があります。まあ後者の方が外国人にとっては合理的なことが多いんですけど）

Answer (score 2):

relative-clausesの[Tag Info](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/relative-clauses/info)を確認すると次のようにありました。

> 連体修飾節（関係節）. A type of subordinate clause which modifies a noun phrase.

実際に「連体修飾節」という語で検索してみると、日本語の文法に関するページが多数ヒットしました。

また、いくつかのページ（[例1](https://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwipyO2qjuDQAhUOPrwKHbqIAXwQFggmMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftakayukiishii.com%2F%25E6%2597%25A5%25E6%259C%25AC%25E8%25AA%259E%25E3%2581%25AB%25E9%2596%25A2%25E4%25BF%2582%25E8%25A9%259E%25E3%2581%258C%25E5%25AD%2598%25E5%259C%25A8%25E3%2581%2597%25E3%2581%25AA%25E3%2581%2584%25E7%2590%2586%25E7%2594%25B1-%25E6%2584%258F%25E5%2591%25B3%25E7%259A%2584%25E9%2596%25A2%25E9%2580%25A3%25E6%2580%25A7-159.html&usg=AFQjCNHN0dVbYzW514gJz3lmSAuXVh9nBw&sig2=uC0fGa5LaYy97NvUUJ6Kfg&bvm=bv.140496471,d.dGc&cad=rja)、[例2](http://www.ravco.jp/cat/view.php?cat_id=4457)、[例3](http://www.eibunpou.net/12/front.html)）では、日本語には関係（代名）詞なる品詞は存在しない、と説明しているところもありました。

そのため、日本語の文法においては「連体修飾節」という語で認識したほうが良さそうな気がします。