# Why is there a noun at the end of this sentence?

Tags: grammar

From [an article on ghosts](http://www.huffingtonpost.jp/2016/03/07/yuka-kudo_n_9398868.html):

> 「私【わたし】は死【し】んだのですか？」と言【い】った直後【ちょくご】に姿【すがた】を消【け】した女性【じょせい】

Comment: Feels like something is missing to me.

Comment: It is  grammatical to end a sentence with a noun.

Comment: Nothing is missing here. It's「体言止め」. Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14524/9831

Comment: Do you know relative clauses?

Answer (score 2):

Simple. That's because it's a ***[relative-clauses](/questions/tagged/relative-clauses)***. It means:

> A woman who disappeared immediately after saying "Am I dead?"

**Relative-clauses** - For example, a sentence like those:

> `<A noun>` (that, who, which...) `<A verb>`

> `<A noun>` (that, who, which...) `<A noun>`+`<A verb>`

In Japanese, its syntax is:

> `<a verb>` `<a noun>`

For more infomation, see:

- [Relative clauses distinguishing whom/with which/that](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14541/14627)
- [日本語における relative clause (関係詞節?) とは？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41503/14627)
- [Relative clause - Wikipedia in English](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause)

  - [関係節](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%96%A2%E4%BF%82%E7%AF%80) (Japanese version)
- [Tag wiki](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/relative-clauses/info) - (But there is no explanation! only excerpt)

Comment: 一行目が意味不明です。いきなり"That's why it is ~~"と言われても、読み手は付いていけません。

Comment: えとね・・・「That's why ～～.」は「そういうわけで～～なのです。」って意味で、多分、「That's because ～～.」「それは/なぜかというと、～～だからです。」って書きたかったんですよね・・（ごめんね、さっき編集したのに全然気づかなかった）

Comment: @l'électeur ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: @Schokolade いえいえ、いつも編集してくださりありがとうございます！