# Are どう、どこ、どれ、どの、等、exclusively question words?

Tags: grammar, meaning, relative-clauses

Are words like 何、いつ、どう、どこ、どれ、どの、exclusively used to request confirmation for a unknown? Or can they also be used to say the Japanese equivalent of things like "This is HOW you do it", or "This is WHEN and WHERE the party's at", like their English counterparts can?

If so, could you provide a few examples of how to use them in this manner.

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13034/5010

Comment: Also: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14541/7810, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41503/7810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are exclusively used in questions and do not quite act like their English counterparts. I tried plugging these words into the examples you provided and found them pretty weird.

With that being said, they can be used in declarative sentences and form clauses that act like nouns, just not after a be-verb (aka, not after "this is"/"you are", etc).

Example: I do not know **when I am making a presentation**.

**いつ発表するか**わからない。
which is equivalent to **発表の時間**がわからない。(I do not know the time of the presentation.)