# usage of 『は』and『が』with adjectives { na-adj and i-adj }

Tags: grammar

i really had this question in my mind and it caused me a lot of pain. 
My question is : 
what is the difference between using ( wa ) and ( ga ) with adjectives ?
 i got confusion because i studied that japanese doesn't have real adjectives , instead it has adjectival verbs ( i-adj ) and adjectival nouns ( na-adj ) and both of them are verbs that modify nouns as it is . and it was mixed up with what i have studied about ( wa ) and ( ga ) , that in the adjective-predicate sentences we should use wa usually . can any one here solve my confusion please . thank you in advance . 
signature : passionate of japanese

Comment: Not really an answer, but I suggest you to tackle the は/が topic on its own, without considering adjectives. As far as I know, any of the three basic types of sentences (adjective-ending sentences, verb-ending sentences and noun-ending sentences) can be combined with either は or が. Perhaps you could provide some examples on your specific issue with は/が combined with adjectives so the community can help you better? Thank you!!

Comment: There are many good answers in the forum covering は vs が, such as [this one](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/54693/32952).

Answer (score 3):

In short, は is used to describe **known/general information**, whereas が is used to report **newly perceived temporary event**. This rule applies regardless of the type of the predicate (i-adjectives / na-adjectives / verbs).

- ポストは赤い。 A mailbox is red. [general/known information]
- 私の車は赤い。 My car is red. [general/known information]
- 信号が赤い。 The traffic light is (currently) red. [newly perceived information]
- 顔が赤いよ。 (I noticed) Your face is being red. [newly perceived information]
- 財布はない。／財布はありません。 I don't have a wallet. [known information]
- 財布がない。／財布がありません。 (I noticed) My wallet is missing! [newly perceived information]

This usage of が to report new information is called "neutral-description ga", 中立描写文, 現象文, 中立叙述文, etc.

See:

- [Can someone explain me the use of は and が in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43213/5010)

  > When you describe or report information which is newly discovered by perception that doesn't include assumption or judgement, Japanese grammar requires you to express it as a sentence whose elements are not topicalized, in short, without adding particles like は.
- [Why does 「電話は切れた」 sound more adversarial than 「電話が切れた」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38639/5010)
- [What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22/5010)

  > Any が can be an exhaustive-listing が, but neutral description only works with action verbs, existential verbs, and adjectives/nominal adjectives that represent state change. "Sentences of neutral description present an objectively observable action, existence, or temporary state as a new event."